# Nature of convergence of the sequence of functions $(f_1(x))^{1/2^n}$ where $f_1$ is continuous $f_1:[0,\infty)\rightarrow[1,\infty)$

Tags: calculus, limits, functions

Given a continuous function $f_1:[0,\infty)\rightarrow[1,\infty)$

Define a sequence of functions recursively by $n\geq1$, $f_{n+1}(x)=\sqrt{f_n(x)}$

Is this sequence of functions

- pointwise convergent?
- uniformly convergent?

If Yes, find the limit function

***Attempt:***

First, we want to see the pattern of the recursive $f_1,f_2,f_3\dots$

$$n=1, f_2(x)=\sqrt{f_1(x)}$$
$$n=2, f_3(x)=\sqrt{\sqrt{f_1(x)}}$$
$$n=3, f_4(x)=\sqrt{\sqrt{\sqrt{f_1(x)}}}$$
$$\vdots$$
$$n\in\mathbb{N},f_{n+1}(x)=\sqrt[2n]{f_1(x)}$$
$$n\in\mathbb{N},f_{n}(x)=\sqrt[2(n-1)]{f_1(x)}$$
$$\sum^{\infty}_{n=1}a_n(x)=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}f_n(x)-f_1(x)$$
$$\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}f_n(x)-f_1(x)=\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\sqrt[2(n-1)]{f_1(x)}-f_1(x)$$

I had to stop here because I think there is a mistake,

I will appreciate that if anyone enlights me.

Comment: For uniform convergence, notice that $\sqrt{0} = 0$ and $\sqrt{1} = 1$ all the time.

For pointwise convergence, you can check (using $\sqrt{t} = e^{\frac{1}{2} \log t}$) that, for $t > 0,$ $\sqrt[2^n]{t} \to 1.$

Comment: Take care, it is not $2(n-1)$ roots but $2^{n-1}$...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For any given $x\in [0,\infty)$, we have the closed form of $f_{n+1}(x)$ from the recursion formula.
$$ f_{n+1}=(f_1(x))^{1/2^n}\rightarrow1,\quad n\rightarrow \infty$$
Hence, the sequence funtions are pointwise convergence.

However, they are probably not uniform convergence. For example,
$$f_1(x)=e^x$$
then $\{f_n(x)\}$ are not uniform convergence.

Comment: First of all, Thanks for the answer, in the example of uniform convergence $e^x$ I need to prove that the example, not uniform convergence may you can write that to be sure in my way?

Comment: @ATB You can calculate $\sup_{x\geq 0}|f_n(x)-1|=+\infty,~~\forall n\in\mathbb{N}$. This leads to that $\{f_n\}$ is not uniform convergence.

Answer (score 0):

Both cases of pointwise, nonuniform convergence and uniform convergence could happen. Take
$$
f_1(x)=x+1
$$
for the first case and
$$
f_1(x)=2-e^{-x}
$$
for the second case. The limit function is always $f(x)=1$ since for any choice of the range of $f_1(x)$, we have
$$
\lim_{n\to \infty} f_1(x)^\frac{1}{2^n}=1.
$$